# Visual Studio 2017 - Solution link not showing

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I go to Visual Studio Team Services (xxxx.visualstudio.com), create a new project, go into Visual Studio 2017, Manage Connections > Connect to Project, select the project and Clone. Create new project message shows up, I create a new .Net Core API. Click on the Team Explorer tab:

[image]

Where is the new solution on the list? I click on Changes:

[image]

Yes, it sees the files that need to be committed, even when solution is not open, there is nothing on the solution explorer. Click the Home Icon on top, again, it's not finding the solution.

I have tried variations of this about 20 times, deleting and recreating, changing the order, etc.

I can click Open, under Solutions, and open the solution, but WHY OH WHY wont it show under Solutions. I don't have this issue in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the change for VS2017. You can click **show Folder view**, it will show solution(s) in solution Explorer.

[image]

> We’re working on transitioning the services formerly provided by the
>   Solution section in Team Explorer to the new “AnyCode” support
>   provided by the Solution Explorer.

Also you can find it in [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2733/solutions-not-shown-in-team-explorer.html).

Comment: 'It's not a bug, it's a feature'... sigh